# Html positioning gap between divs

Tags: css, html, layout

im having a html layout issue below is the code, when you open the page there is a space between the menu bar and the grey box I would like to get rid of the space so there is only a small gap between them, if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<title>Cleveland Potash Intranet</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    margin-right: 0px;
}s
#bannerdiv {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style4 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.auto-style5 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>




<div id="bannerdiv" align="left" title="Banner">
    </div>
<div id="container">
    <h3 class="auto-style4" id="container">&nbsp;</h3>
</div>
<div id="menubar" style="width: 15%; height: 100px;" title="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" style="height: 20px" class="auto-style5">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" style="height: 20px">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" style="height: 20px; width: 121px;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>


    </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainpage" class="auto-style1" style="height: 96px; width:   84%; float:right;height:84%; color: #000000; font-size: 11pt;"> 
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #008852;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 10%;
}

#main
{
height:100%;
weight:100&
}

html, body {
overflow: hidden;
height:100%;}

#menubar

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #EFF1EB;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #638529;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
#mainpage {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px ;
}
#menubar {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: xx-small;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top:11px;
    float: left;
}
#bannerdiv 
{

    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.newStyle1 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Pff, CSS at 3 places.... The main reason is `15 + 84 = 99%` width! Perhaps you need to use [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) and place CSS only in the `.css` file. Not inline, not in the `<style>` tag

Comment: you have identical IDs. Not good HTML coding style. IDs should be unique, i.e., one instance each

Comment: and avoid inline CSS (style="/* don't use me */")

Comment: here's a jsFiddle for people to work on: http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/q8z5U/

Answer (score 0):

Change the inline styling width on the `id="menubar"` from 15% to 10% and add a `min-width` element set at 130px. Then remove the inline `float:right;` from the `id="mainpage"` and also change its `width` to be 89%. That should improve the spacing, but it's worth mentioning that inline styles are not a good way of styling html. You should be defining all of your styles in a css document that is linked to the html file.